# ¿Por qué mi clave foránea (FK) en una tabla se pone como FK en otra tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server, diseño, arquitectura

De acuerdo con la siguiente imagen:

[image: Compra]

En la relación **`Compra — DetalleCompra`**, en `DetalleCompra`, ¿necesito `ProveedorId`?, ¿está de más?, ¿Por qué la herramienta case pone el **`(FK)`** en las otras tablas cuando sólo se necesita el ID de la tabla?

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta está incluida en tu texto: _"no necesito ProvedorId"_. Te recuerdo que las preguntas que piden opiniones se consideran _off topic_ por lo que deberías incluir un problema específico que tenga una respuesta puntual.

Comment: puedes cambiar el titulo quitando el "que apinan" a plantear el problema de diseño del modelo de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se está agregando `ProveedorId` porque en la tabla `Compra` defines una *clave primaria compuesta*, por eso visualizas los campos `CompraId` y `ProveedorId` por encima de la línea que los separa del resto.

Elimina como parte de la *clave primaria* de la tabla Compra al `ProveedorId` y verás como esto hace que desaparezca de `DetalleCompra`.

Answer (score 0):

Debes eliminar la relación de las tabla compra y proveedor por que esa relación ya la tienes en detalle compra